# How can I create a rounded arrow box using css3?

Tags: border, shapes, css

using the below I can make a bit of a rounded arrow:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 20px 50px 50px 20px;
border-radius: 20px 50px 50px 20px;
```

But it is not sharp enough, the arrow box must have a fluid height so it can contain text that is responsive. Is this possible to do with css3? You can see what I'm trying to achieve by going to http://dev.aaronpitts.ch/lhc/ and clicking on the SDBS box. I just want more of an arrowed right side.

Many thanks

Comment: So you're not looking for a perfectly triangular arrow? Can you perhaps post a Paint drawing of what you're looking for?

Comment: try using viewport relative units?

Comment: http://border-radius.com/

If you want it to appear more as an arrow,  why not use a icon-font kit where you can use an actual arrow?  Or use a responsive background image?  I don't think border-radius is going to get as sharp as you are needing.

Comment: you can have a sharped arrow, but i dont believe it could be responsive, especially for the height. if it is good with a fixed height, like in the example, i can try something with just css

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div id="arrow">
    <p>This is a content</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#arrow {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border: 0.2em solid darkgreen;
    border-radius: 2em 5em 5em 2em;
    height: 5em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 10em;
}
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/mJLd4/2/)

Using `em` data unit you'll have a size that will change based on the size of the font of your client. Bigger text size means a bigger arrow and a bigger radius, the same for small texts. This way you can have an adaptive arrow.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with your border radius values here:

http://www.css3generator.in/border-radius.html

If you can't get what you want with that tool, you're going to need to look for a more complicated solution. Here's one that uses a span element, a css rotation, and jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/nG6xZ/5/

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div{
    background:#aaeeee;
    border:2px solid #99dddd;
    border-radius: 30px 5px 5px 30px/30px 5px 5px 30px;
    padding:10px;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
div .arrow {
    background:#aaeeee;
    border:2px solid #99dddd;
    border-width:2px 2px 0 0;
    position:absolute;
    right:-17px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-16px;

    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    display:block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-radius:5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Text Here</div>
<div>Text<br />Here</div>
<script>
$('div').each(function() {
    $(this).append('<span class="arrow"></span>');
});
var resizeArrow = function() {
    $('span.arrow').each(function() {
        var parent = $(this).parent(),
            height = parseInt(parent.css('height'),10),
            padding = parseInt(parent.css('padding-top'),10)*2,
            border = parseInt(parent.css('border-top-width'),10)*2,
            hypotenuse = height + padding + border,
            sides = Math.sqrt((hypotenuse * hypotenuse) / 2);
        $(this).css({
            "width":sides+"px",
            "height":sides+"px",
            "right":-sides/2+"px",
            "margin-top":-sides/2+"px"
        });
    });
}
$(window).ready(resizeArrow);
$(window).resize(resizeArrow);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```